# Data through socket.io sent by server displays unpredictably

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, strapi

In my case, Socket.io acts very unstably. It is needed to make it more debuggable and stable.
**Introduction**
There is a Node'js based backend (Strapi CMS), wherein `bootstrap.js` I have a right to run my custom code - in my case the socket server:

```js
module.exports = async () => {
  process.nextTick(() =>{
    var io = require('socket.io')(strapi.server);
    io.on('connection', async function(socket) {
      
      console.log(`a user connected`)
      
      // send a message on user connection
      socket.emit('question', {message: await strapi.services.question.findOne({ id: 1 })});
      
      //Send a message after a timeout of 4seconds
      setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit('endEvent', { description: 'A custom event named EndEvent!'});
      }, 4000);
      // listen for user diconnect
      socket.on('disconnect', () =>{
        console.log('a user disconnected')
      });
    });
    strapi.io = io; // register socket io inside strapi main object to use it globally anywhere
  })
};
```

This server is expected to send a question from the database to the socket via custom event -`question`. The frontend runs with ReactJS. Whenever the page is loaded the socket is created, it establishes a connection with the server and receives the `question` event from the server, and the data of the quiz question, which is printed as an object.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:1337";
const socket = io(ENDPOINT);

function Question() {
  const [questionID,setQuestionID] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', (data)=> {setResponse(data)});
    socket.on('endEvent', ()=>{console.log('End event done.')})
    socket.on('question', (msg, cb) => {
      console.log( msg.message)
    });
    // CLEAN UP THE EFFECT
    return () => socket.disconnect();
  }, [questionID]);
return(<p>The question debugable from console</p>);
}
export default Question;
```

**Problem**.
When I refresh the page, the `console.log( msg.message)` does print on time, but not each time. Sometimes it just prints when some other component of React is being triggered. For detailed info please see screenshots. This is expected:
[image: Strapi socket.io]
It prints the object of `question` and also `End event done.` Which is triggered by the server in 4 seconds right after the connection. Instability shows itself when **both of the commands run twice**, or the object of the `question` itself delays to display anyhow.
[image]
I am not sure if the question is not being sent from the server or it is not printed in the console on client-side... The `useEffect()` is loaded at first, then triggered each time whenever `questionID` is changed.
**Unexplained behavior**
When the countdown time component triggers that the time is expired, you may mention that the 2 important commands of printing and 4 seconds session delay are somehow triggered, which is unexplainable for me, how two independent components of ReactJS may "not fit".
On the server-side, I receive information "connected" and "disconnected" when refreshed. Please comment if an update is needed or have a suggestion for a better title.